# Can i pursue a career in data science with a business analytics degree?

Tags: education, career

I had a question regarding about a career as a data scientist.  Im pursuing a degree in business analytics with a minor computer science.  Could i still become a data scientist with a bachelors degree in business analytics. Or would i have to pursue a masters degree in data science in order to become a data scientist.

(I have a good programming background in data structures and algorithm in java, plus web development, python)

Comment: Yes, but not easily. Want it bad enough to put in years of work, feel stupid very often, and continually push your brain into new and uncomfortable areas? Didn't hesitate? Definitely do it! A list of classes is one thing, but don't underestimate what @AN6U5 says about academic maturity. It requires conditioning and disciplining your brain to think in a certain way that most people don't ever do.  I'm sure you're capable. It's a huge effort for anyone. Some make it look easy, remember they've spent a big chuck of life developing these skills. It's 2017 - hope your path has been auspicious.

Answer (score 2):

You can. Nobody is going to demand a degree, but they will expect you to pass the interviews. I would recommend creating a blog and do some Kaggle competitions to show off your skills. I would also recommend taking more serious maths courses from the statistics department.

Comment: linear algebra? cause i have taken statistics courses in college

Comment: Linear algebra is a must. Take some machine learning courses too.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on you, your ability to apply your knowledge of statistics, computer science and mathematics to abstract problems and also your problem solving intuition and prowess. A great many jobs in the US require Masters or Ph.D.s, but there are some that do not. But add to this, your lack of a degree in a truly quantitative discipline and it might make things tough.

Though you have cited some background in statistics, being a data science requires that you have the mathematical maturity to digest research papers and text books to apply abstract concepts to the real world. This typically requires the experience that is common to a mathematics BS or a Masters or Ph.D. in a slightly less rigorous field like engineering.

I would certainly consider taking 2 years of calculus and enough linear algebra to get past matrix manipulation and really understand Fourier analysis, orthogonal vector spaces and Hilbert space.

I would advise you to seriously consider a Masters or Ph.D. program. If you don't want to do this, then try to take full advantage of your CSE minor to be a really strong programmer. You should be able to find a job in a smaller startup which will allow you to prove yourself over time. Be prepared that a lot of first time jobs may be Data Engineer positions, which require a lot of ETL and data munging.

Good luck in whatever you decide to pursue!